# Double Loop absolute value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set up a code that displays a message when a cell's value is higher than each of the 5 previous cells in the same column.

This is my code:

```
Sub IncreasingFor_5Steps()

Dim i, j As Integer

For i = 7 To 20
    For j = 1 To 5
        If Cells(i, 5).Value > Cells(i - j, 5).Value Then    
            Cells(i, 6) = "Increased for 5 steps"    
        End If        
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

When I run this code, the message **"Increased for 5 steps"** is displayed when the cell is higher than AT LEAST one cell (over the 5 previous cells), but what I would like is to display the message ONLY IF the cells is higher than ALL 5 previous cells, but I don't know how to do.

See this for example in F7 the message is displayed whereas E7 is lower than E4, also E20 is lower than E19 but the message is displayed though, because E20 is higher than E15, E16, E17, E18, but I don't want that:

[image],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, you need a boolean flag to go around it:

```
Sub IncreasingFor_5Steps()

    Dim i       As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim flag    As Boolean

    For i = 7 To 20
        flag = False
        For j = 1 To 5
            If Cells(i, 5).Value <= Cells(i - j, 5).Value Then
                flag = True
            End If
        Next j
        If Not flag Then Cells(i, 6) = "Increased for 5 steps"
    Next i

End Sub
```

The idea of the boolean flag is that it checks all the 5 cells for being smaller and if one of them is not smaller, then it becomes `true` Once it is true, the `Cells(i,6)` does not increment.

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can do it simply with this formula:

`=IFERROR(IF(MAX(OFFSET(E1,-5,0))<E1,"Increased for 5 steps",""),"")`

Answer (score 1):

Is doing this in VBA necessary?  Would placing this formula in F7 and drag down work?

```
=IF(E7>MAX(E2:E6),"Increased for 5 steps","")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **VBA**, you can use the `WorksheetFunction.Max` to get the maximum value in a certain range, and thus eliminating the need to have 2 `For` loops.

```
Option Explicit

Sub IncreasingFor_5Steps()

Dim i As Long

For i = 7 To 20
    ' use WorkshettFunction Max instead of a 2nd loop
    If Cells(i, 5).Value > WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(i - 5, 5), Cells(i - 1, 5))) Then
        Cells(i, 6) = "Increased for 5 steps"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```